# Where is the first place I can call a service in angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app and I am using ui-router.

I need to call my service at the beginning of my App before anything else runs.

Is there a way I can call a service inside of my app.js file without using app.run? Or is there a better solution other than in my app.js file?

Comment: Why do you need to run your service before everything else? Why does the run block not good enough?

Comment: Great question. I am authenticating against my server from an ios device and to log in a current user I need to run my service before the app runs.    When I use the run block it doesn't get called unless I use a $timeout in order to install all of the necessary packages first and by that time my login template loads before the service can be called. @OrGuz

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the resolve functionality of ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference. You just add another field to your state called 'resolve' and then can inject the service there. By using a resolve, this route will not execute until this resolve is completed.

I have something similar in an application where I created an abstract state for others to inherit and therefore, none of the states are registered until that initial resolve function is completed.

Ex.

```
$stateProvider.state('someState', {
    template: 'someTemplate.html', 
    controller: 'someController', 
    resolve: {
        authenticate: function(AuthSrv){
            //Do stuff with AuthSrv in here
        }
    }
})
```